# Map over a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do this:

```
list(map(lambda x: x.name, my_dict))
```

where `my_dict` is a dict of form `k, v` where `v` is an object and `v.name` is defined.

The problem is it is using the key `k` for `x` where I really want to use the value `v`.

**In other words:**
How do I map over the values of a dict?

PS I want to avoid `my_dict[x]` as I will be using `concurrent.futures` and won't be passing the full dict into separate threads.

Comment: print list(map(lambda x: x, my_dict.values()))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To retrieve view of values, you may use `.values` method.

```
map(callable, my_dict.values())
```

Obviously, `map` with trivial callables usually can be avoided in Python by using list or generator comprehensions.

```
[x.name for x in my_dict.values()]  # creates list: non-lazy
(x.name for x in my_dict.values())  # creates generator: lazy
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `map()` and then convert the result to a list. Instead you can use simply use a list comprehension by looping over the dictionary values:

```
[v.name for v in my_dict.values()]
```

Or still if you are looking for a functional approach you can use `attrgetter` function from operator module :

```
from operator import attrgetter
map(attrgetter('name'), my_dict.values())
```